# When docked, do Dragon solar panels contribute to ISS mains power?

Tags: spacex, iss, solar-power, power, dragon

What it says on the tin.

Does a docked Dragon trunk section contribute to the ISS's batteries? I'm aware it would probably be minimal though due to orientation and occlusion of the panels, and when not in use, the spacecraft's internal power draw is likely minimal.

Comment: No factual knowledge about this, but it is *highly* unlikely. The contribution would be very small, and the required safety & conditioning devices needed to *ensure* that an aberrant external power source does not compromise the system would be... extravagant in its needs.

Comment: The Dragon spaceship at the ISS should be ready for emergency undocking in a very short time. So the temperature of all electronics should be within limits, the batteries fully charged and the navigation computer ready for undocking. How much power would be available for contribution to the ISS?

Comment: A docked shuttle was electrically connected, so it's not impossible, but I also doubt it (without any proof).